# Create a map with values of one map as key and values of second map as values?

Tags: java, collections

I have below two . A List of Maps and a Map

```
Map<String, String> one = new HashMap<>();
one.put("Medicine","Doctor");
one.put("Engineering","Engineer");

Map<String, String> two =new HashMap<>();
two.put("Medicine","MBBS");
two.put("Engineering","Software Engineer");

Map<String, String> three = new HasMap<>();
three.put("Medicine","Ortho");
three.put("Engineering","Aerospace Engineer")

List<Map<String, String>> four= new ArrayList<>();
for(Map<String, String> eachMap: four){
     Map<String, String> singleMapFromList= new HashMap<>();
     //help me here
}
```

Now I want values of first map(one) as key to fourth map(four) for the values of second map(two) and third map(three).

Required output for reference

```
{ Doctor : MBBS, Engineering : Software Engineer }
{ Doctor : Ortho, Engineering : Aerospace Engineer }
```

Please help me finding a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Required output should be `Engineer=Software Engineer`

Comment: @user16320675. Sorry typo.

Comment: You will likely need to define what is required when the key from `one` has no corresponding entry in `two`.  Is `null` acceptable for the value in `three`, for example.  Or for that matter, if the value from `one` is null.

Comment: @Andy. Null is acceptable only when the value of second map is null for a key. But first map will alway have a key and a value.

Comment: Please don't add additional requirements after the question has been posted.  Just ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest one of the following depending on your data.  The first is the simplest.

```
Map<String, String> one = new HashMap<>();
one.put("Medicine", "Doctor");
one.put("Engineering", "Engineer");
    
Map<String, String> two = new HashMap<>();
two.put("Medicine", "MBBS");
two.put("Engineering", "Software Engineer");
```

- first I stream the keys
- then I filter to ensure that the other map has mapped value.  Otherwise, the new map will have key mapping to a `null`.
- then I just create the map using the values from the two maps as the key/value pair of the target map.

```
Map<String, String> map1 =
                one.keySet().stream().filter(two::containsKey)
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(one::get,
                                two::get));

map1.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Engineer=Software Engineer
Doctor=MBBS
```

But what if you have different keys in the maps that map to the same value?  You could end up trying to put duplicates in the final map and that would cause an error.  Here is an example to take care of that.

Two more values are added to maps `one` and `two` to demonstrate.

```
one.put("Chemist", "Doctor");  // Doctor would be a duplicate key.
two.put("Chemist", "Professor");
```

- as before, streams the keys and filter to avoid null values
- the keys will be the values from map `one`
- But the values will be placed in a list in case duplicate keys appear
- the `mapping` state pulls the value from the second map and adds it to a list

```
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = one.keySet().stream()
    .filter(two::containsKey)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(one::get,
                Collectors.mapping(
                        two::get,
                        Collectors.toList())));

map2.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
Engineer=[Software Engineer]
Doctor=[MBBS, Professor]
```

Of course, the choice is yours based on your intimate knowledge of your data.

Comment: Can you look at the edited question.

Comment: I just edited the question. And the new map can have a key mapped to a null

Comment: Ok, so the filter `.filter(two::containsKey)` can simply be removed if you don't mind about mapping to nulls.

Comment: BTW, when you edited your question you moved the goal posts. Originally you just had two maps, `one` and `two`  whose values were supposed to be the new key/value pairs of the target map.   Now you added more requirements.  If you have other requirements outside of your original question then please just ask a new question.

Comment: Sure. I will post a new question. Please provide me an answer

Comment: Well, it may not be me but someone will.

Comment: Please answers this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69826629/create-a-map-with-values-of-one-map-as-key-and-values-of-each-map-as-values-from

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238839/discussion-between-vishal-ekkaldevi-and-wjs).

Answer (score 1):

Example implementation using `keySet` from map `one`:

```java
Map<String, String> joined = one.keySet()
    .stream()  // Stream<String> keys
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        one::get, // key   - value from map one
        two::get, // value - value from map two
        (v1, v2) -> v1 // merge function to resolve possible conflicts
    ));
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this ...

```
// Stream the first map 
Map<String, String> result = one.entrySet()
.stream()
.collect(
   Collectors.toMap(
     // The value from the first map becomes the key in the third map
     Map.Entry::getValue,
     // Use key from the first map to get the value from the second map 
     // and store it as value in the third map
     e -> two.get(e.getKey()))
);
```