# Create a map with values of one map as key and values of each map as values from a list of maps

Tags: java, collections

I have a List of Maps and a Map like below

```java
Map<String, String> one = new HashMap<>();
one.put("Medicine","Doctor");
one.put("Engineering","Engineer");

Map<String, String> two =new HashMap<>();
two.put("Medicine","MBBS");
two.put("Engineering","Software Engineer");

Map<String, String> three = new HashMap<>();
three.put("Medicine","Ortho");
three.put("Engineering","Aerospace Engineer");

List<Map<String, String>> four= new ArrayList<>();
four.add(two);
four.add(three); // there could be more

List<Map<String, String>> result= new ArrayList<>();
for(Map<String, String> eachMap: four){
     Map<String, String> singleMapFromList= new HashMap<>();
     //help me here
     result.add(singleMapFromList);
}
```

Now I want values of first map(one) as key to each new map(singleMapFromList) for the values of second map(two) and third map(three) and so on

Required output for reference

```
{ Doctor : MBBS, Engineer : Software Engineer }
{ Doctor : Ortho, Engineer : Aerospace Engineer }
//more
```

Please help me finding a solution.

Comment: Should `Engineering` in required output be `Engineer`?

Comment: Sorry Engineer is required.

Comment: What attempts have you made to solve this?

Comment: Getting the entryset for each map from list of maps and from the entry set i got the key and with that key i got the value from map(one). Then i added them in the new map as key value pair(key --> value from map one, value --> value of each map associated with the key from map one

Comment: Please edit your question to add that code and explain why it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> result = four.stream()  // iterate the Map with values
   .map(map -> map.entrySet()                     // .. for each one
           .stream()                              // .. stream and collect
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(             // .. into a new Map
                   e -> one.get(e.getKey()),      // .. with a key from the `one` Map
                   Map.Entry::getValue)))         // .. and the same value
   .collect(Collectors.toList());                 // and pack as a List
```

The output on calling `result.forEach(System.out::println);` is (remember that `HashMap` is unordered):

```
{Engineer=Software Engineer, Doctor=MBBS}
{Engineer=Aerospace Engineer, Doctor=Ortho}
```

If you want the keys in each map sorted, you need to use the `TreeMap` implementation and an overloaded [`Collectors.toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator, Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-). However, the default behavior of the merger `BinaryOperator` in the previous [`Collectors.toMap(Function, Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) method is that it throws an exception on duplicated keys. You have to implement this one by yourself.

```
BinaryOperator<String> throwingMerger = (u,v) -> { 
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Duplicate key %s", u)); 
};
        
List<Map<String, String>> result = four.stream() // iterate the Map with values
    .map(map -> map.entrySet()                     // .. for each one
            .stream()                              // .. stream and collect
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(             // .. into a new Map
                    e -> one.get(e.getKey()),      // .. with a key from the `one` Map
                    Map.Entry::getValue,           // .. and the same value
                    throwingMerger,                // .. failing fast on duplicated keys
                    TreeMap::new)))                // .. as TreeMap
    .collect(Collectors.toList());                 // and pack as a List
```

```
{Doctor=MBBS, Engineer=Software Engineer}
{Doctor=Ortho, Engineer=Aerospace Engineer}
```

Comment: Good explanation! I recommend you do it as `List<Map<String, String>> result = four.stream().map(map -> map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> one.get(e.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue, (s1, s2) -> s1, LinkedHashMap::new))).collect(Collectors.toList());` to keep the order intact.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolas Charalambidis. That really solved my problem. But just out of curiosity, i want to know if the values of map( one) are the keys of map (two, three ... So on). How to handle this type of requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Arvind Kumar Avinash. Please feel free to answer my question to Nikolas

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash: Thanks! The inner stream still results in an unordered map and `TreeMap` would help to sort the keys alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolas Charalambidis. Please answer this question with the requirement i mentioned above.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69829621/new-map-with-keys-of-one-map-mapped-to-values-of-other-maps